# Значення слова "кнехт"

Tags: вживання-слів, значення-слів, іменники, запозичені-слова

У [Словнику чужомовних слів і термінів](https://archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt) натрапляю на такі відповідники:

> **Кнехт** - **вояк** (найманий), див. **найманець**

Однак якщо глянути на значення слова "кнехт" у [СУМ-11](http://sum.in.ua/s/knekhty), то воно **≠** пропонованим відповідникам:

> **КНЕ́ХТИ, ів, мн. (одн. кнехт, а, чол.). Парні тумби на палубі судна або на пристані для закріплювання канатів, снастей.** Андрій і Марко скочили на берег і почали кріпити трос, обмотуючи ним береговий кнехт (Микола Трублаїні, Шхуна.., 1940, 16).

Отож у "Словнику чужомовних слів і термінів" помилка? Адже СУМ-11 подає лише одне значення.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У  [Практичному словнику виробничої термінології](https://archive.org/stream/slovvirobnichiy/alovnyk_virobnichiy_djvu.txt) також знаходимо:

**Кнехт** (речн.) - *кнага*.

У [Вікіпедії](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0) бачимо:

> **Кна́га**[1] (від пол. knaga) - дільна річ на судні, що являє собою дворогу металеву планку, закріплену на палубі (чи на іншій частині судна). Призначена для кріплення рухомого такелажу.< … >На невеликих вітрильних судах (наприклад, яхтах) кнага жорстко кріпиться до корпусу й може використовуватися для кріплення якірних, швартовних, буксирних та інших тросів, замінюючи собою **кнехт**.

Отже,  це значення у [Словнику чужомовних слів і термінів](https://archive.org/stream/shtepa1977/shtepa1977_djvu.txt) = [СУМу](http://sum.in.ua/s/knekhty).
Тобто, слово **кнехт** має 2 значення ( не думаю, що це помилка).

Також маємо підтвердження цих значень у [Вікіпедії](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%82).

Answer (score 2):

Просто ці слова різного походження: "кнехт" у значенні *найманець*, *слуга*, *батрак* походить з німецької [[1]](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B4%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%82), [[2]](https://translate.google.com/#de/uk/Knecht), а "кнехти" у значенні тумби для швартування походить з нідерландської [[3]](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%82%D1%8B_(%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD)), [[4]](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%85%D1%82).

Схожа річ трапилась і з словом **кран**. У значенні вантажопідіймальної машини воно прийшло з [німецької](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%96%D0%B4%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD) від слова [der Kanich](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kranich), що означає [журавель](https://uk.glosbe.com/de/uk/Kranich), а у значенні трубопровідного крану пішло від нідерландського [kraan](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD_(%D0%B3%D1%96%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B0)).